# How to display an error message when pd.read.csv fails

Tags: python, pandas

I use pd.read_csv to fetch GCS data.
However, when the file size is too large or something, the python task force quit
automatically at the line using pd.read_csv without displaying the error message.
I would like to display an error message to improve the script and catch the error.
How can I do that?

```py
    appended_data = []
    print('loop start')
    for blob in self.client.list_blobs(self.bucket, prefix=prefix):
        if re.match(regexp_file_path, blob.name):
            print('fetch')
            df = pd.read_csv('gs://{}/{}'.format(self.bucket, blob.name), names=columns, sep='\t')
            print('append')
            appended_data.append(df)

    print('loop end')
```

and, the result is below

```
loop start
fetch
append
fetch
append
fetch
append
fetch
append
fetch
append
fetch
```

I expected the script prints "append" and "loop end", but the script force quits with the last message "fetch".

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for gs://, but you can add `chunksize` parameter when you call `pd.read_csv`. It'll return an iterator of dataframes each with `chunksize` number of rows. With this at least you can pin point a range of index that was causing your script to fail.

Comment: Thanks. I used the chunksize parameter to make this script successful. It worked, but I still couldn't detect the failure of the script. I will execute this script as a daily batch job so I surely would like to detect that.

Comment: If the script still fails even with a small chunksize, then it might be that the data in one of the row is too big. Also, if you are keeping all the fetched rows in memory (your `appended_data` list) without freeing them, the list will eventually become too big causing memory error.

Comment: Thanks, does memory error fail without displaying a message? And Yes, I keep appended_data in memory. How to free them? The only way I know is to write data in storage like CSV. Do you know any other ideas?